How could Amram have seen Jacob given Biblical chronology?
The Talmud says that Amram saw Jacob (Bava Batra 121b).  But Exodus 12:40 says that the sons of Israel were in Egypt for 430 years.  Aaron was 83 during the Exodus, and Amram lived to be 137, and Jacob lived to be 147.  So this means that Jacob was born at most 367 years before the Exodus.  So even if Ex 12:40 is talking about the time in Egypt and Canaan, how can this be possible because Israel himself didn't exist 430 years before the Exodus, so his sons couldn't have done anything.  In fact not even Isaac existed 430 years before the Exodus.

According to traditional Jewish sources, the sojourn in Egypt was 210 years. The number 430 refers to the length of time from the Covenant of the Pieces (ברית בין הבתרים) to the Exodus, which was defined as a kind of sojourn spread across Canaan, Goshen and Egypt. See e.g., Tanchuma Miketz 8:1; Rashi on Genesis 15:13; Rashi on Exodus 12:40 (based on Mechilta de-Rabbi Yishmael 14:15); Beresheet Rabbah 63:3; Seder Olam Rabbah ch. 3.
